# Problema com alocação dinâmica

Tags: c, memória, alocação

Preciso fazer um código em que o usuário preencha um vetor quantas vezes ele quiser, porém o código para de rodar. Se eu registrar apenas 3 valores, como (1) (2) (3) ele funciona normalmente, mas em alguns momentos (não existe padrão) o programa para de ser executado. Não consegui achar minha falha.

Segue o código:

```
#include<stdio.h>

main(){
int *vetor, i, d, contador=0; 
char c;
vetor=NULL;
do{
    if(contador==0)
        vetor=malloc(1*sizeof(int));
    else
        realloc(vetor,1*sizeof(int));
printf("Digite um valor para salvar no vetor: ");
scanf("%d", &d);
*(vetor+contador)=d;
contador++;
printf("Deseja cadastrar mais um numero? ");
scanf(" %c", &c);
system("pause");
} while(c == 's' || c == 'S');
system("cls");
for(i=0; i<contador; i++)
    printf(" (%d) ", vetor[i]);
}
```

Comment: o seu `realloc` está realocando o mesmo espaço tente `realloc(vetor,tamanho*sizeof(int));` onde para cada loop o `tamanha` incrementa +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O principal problema e que a realocação está usando o mesmo tamanho sempre, não está aumentando e não está atribuindo para uma variável, esta realocação se perde, isto gera o erro. Tem maneiras melhores para resolver isto, mas para um exercício está bom. Mude:

```
vetor = realloc(vetor, sizeof(int) * contador + 1);
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/0VnPhY). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/wlmwikkx-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Allocation/ReallocSize.c). Reformulei pra um jeito que eu gosto mais e bem mais organizado. Em código real eu faria um pouco diferente ainda

Comment: Realmente, alterei aqui e funcionou, e o melhor de tudo: entendi pq estava errado! Muitíssimo obrigado, Abraço!

Comment: Se o `realloc()`falhar e devolver `NULL` perdes a referencia ao `vetor`. É preferivel usar uma variavel auxiliar: `vetortmp = realloc(vetor, ...); if (!vetortmp) /* erro; vetor ainda esta valido */; vetor = vetortmp;`